Clip a cascaded WFS-layer in GeoServer and redistribute as a WFS
I have a cascaded WFS-layer in GeoServer. The extent is a large area, and I would like to have only a part of it and share that through my own WFS. Is there a way to clip or "hide" parts the cascaded WFS? The area I want to clip is a municipality, so a simple four corner bounding box is not enough. Should I use a CQL filter and insert the municipality's geometry? I understand that GeoFence also provides some functionality for spatial filtering but I have no previous experience with GeoFence? What would be my best options?
The cascaded WFS layer does not contain any attributes that could help with filtering (so there's no municipality column).

In theory you can pass the geometry of your municipality to the WFS server by setting a CQL filter on the layer you are publishing. But this assumes that the server can handle the request you are cascading. With my favourite government test WFS (which happens to be a ESRI server) it barfs when I send it a reasonably detailed boundary (even after I clicked the prefer POST check box in the WFS store). But as it simply returns a 403 rather than any sort of useful error message I can't tell if it doesn't like the filter (despite advertising it) or the length of the geometry so YMMV.

Thanks Ian for your answer! I'll accept your answer! In reality the server was not able to handle the request properly, but in theory it worked.
We are now trying a workaround, where we use a scheduled script (once every night) that collects the needed data from the WFS and saves it to the server as a GeoPackage. Then that GeoPackge is used for as the store for the WFS that we share.
